# Can group by clause take user inputs in spring boot jpa?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created a query in Spring boot Jpa using @query. It goes like

```
@Query(
    "select id,sum(col_a),sum(col_b),
    weekcal(to_date(?2,'mm/dd/yyyy'),weekof) as startofweek 
    from abc_table 
    where id=?1 and 
    weekof between to_date(?2,'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date(?3,'mm/dd/yyyy')
    group by weekcal(to_date(?2,'mm/dd/yyyy'),weekof),id")
List<object_abc> method_abc(String id,String fromdate,String todate)
```

I get this error trace when i run my test case :

> [WARN] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error:
>   979, SQLState: 42000 [ERROR]
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00979: not a
>   GROUP BY expression

NOTE: weekcal is my user defined function in SQl which takes two date parameters and returns a varchar. weekof is a column name.

can group by take user input as arguments in JPA, because the same query works fine when i hard code any date Example '01-17-2016' instead of ordinal (?2).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The query is clearly INVALID JPQL. There is no "weekcal", "to_date" in JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

> @Query("SELECT c.currency, SUM(c.population) FROM Country c WHERE c.continents GROUP BY c.currency HAVING COUNT(c) > 1")
>
> int getCurrencyCount(@Param("currency") Long currency,@Param("population") Long population, @Param("continents ") String continents)

you can find more examples here 
[JPA Query Structure](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/structure)